# Qt 5.5 - Visual Studio Add-in - where is the Run Qmake button?

Tags: qt5, qmake

In Qt 5.0 when I right-clicked on the project, there was a 'Run Qmake' button.
Where is it now?

Answer (score 0):

In [this](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2016/03/16/qt-5-6-released/) blog post it is mentioned that Visual Studio add-in doesn't work with Visual Studio 2015 anymore due to some changes of Microsoft. There is also a [bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTVSADDINBUG-404) already.
If you use an older version of Visual Studio the add-in should still work.